# The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel - client issues

Tags: .net, ssl-certificate, tls1.2

I'm having issues with SSL handshake in one of our projects.
There is a 2 say SSL certificate required.

Security protocol is set to TLS12 (and tested with others as well TLS1,SSL3) and also certifcate callback is properly done. The problem is that the code works on workstations but not on any servers (win 2008 or 2012).

The error we are receiving is:  `The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.`
We actually don't get any server certificate callback on any of the servers.

Here is the codesnippet when we load cert. We are using .NET framework:

`cert = new X509Certificate2("certpath", "pass", X509KeyStorageFlags.DefaultKeySet)
 client.ClientCertificates.Add(cert);`

From what it seems the certificate chain is OK, because we can access to the WSDL with browser.

**To SUM up:** We can access to endpoint with workstation but not with the server. However the endpoint as accessible from browser (after certificate selection)

Comment: Use tools like Wireshark to capture TLS handshake packets and then compare different scenarios. It is rather normal for Windows Server 2008 (R2 or not) as it is end-of-life. For Windows Server 2012 and above, you need to check Client Hello/Server Hello carefully.

Answer (score 0):

Lex Li pointed me to the right direction. 
When using wireshark I have noticed the Client Hello (my client was runnning on  server 2008 R2 and 2012 R2) reached the destination server but it has returned handshake fail.

After detailed inspection I have noticed the Cipher Suites from my client app on server 2008 R2 (or server 2012 R2) did not match the Cipher Suite on destination server.